# Why can't my subclass of IKImageBrowserView->NSView->NSResponder be made first responder?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, first-responder, imagekit

I have this line calling `-makeFirstResponder`:

```
[self.window makeFirstResponder:libraryViewController.imageBrowser];
```

`imageBrowser` is of type `CaptureBrowserView`, a subclass of `IKImageBrowserView`, which is a subclass of `NSView` which is a subclass of `NSResponder`

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet CaptureBrowserView *imageBrowser;
@interface CaptureBrowserView : IKImageBrowserView
@interface IKImageBrowserView : NSView <NSDraggingSource> {
@interface NSView : NSResponder <NSAnimatablePropertyContainer, NSUserInterfaceItemIdentification, NSDraggingDestination, NSAppearanceCustomization, NSAccessibilityElement, NSAccessibility>
```

But I get this error:

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'CaptureBrowserView *' to parameter
>   of type 'NSResponder *'

Am I overlooking something obvious?  Or is an IKImageBrowserView, for some reason, specifically unable to become the first responder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you actually `#import "CaptureBrowserView.h"` in the file that does `makeFirstResponder:`? If the compiler has only seen a forward declaration of `CaptureBrowserView` at that point, it doesn't know that it's an `NSResponder`.

Comment: Amazing, I figured I was overlooking something.  Thanks!